# Is "inveterate" always pejorative?

Tags: meaning

Clearly, the most common usage of this is "inveterate liar." I don't think I've ever heard this word used in a positive sense.

You never hear of an "inveterate philanthropist," for example.

Does usage of this word inherently describe a negative trait?

Comment: Not by definition 'having a habit... that is long-established and unlikely to change' (Oxford). See [this](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/inveterate)

Comment: Obviously not, since Google Books has ***hundreds*** of written instances of [***inveterate cheerfulness***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22inveterate+cheerfulness%22).

Comment: ...but there's definitely a *bias* towards the negative, given that if I search NGrams for " **inveterate** * ", it tells me the most common words to follow ***inveterate*** (in "popularity" order) are ***enemy, hatred, habit, hostility, prejudice, foe,...***

Comment: ...also note that Google Books has at least a couple of dozen written instances of the collocation [*"**inveterate philanthropist**"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22inveterate+philanthropist%22).

Comment: Any time you're discussing a trait that can be attributed to a human, there will be a preponderance of negative or pejorative terms. Basic human nature.

Comment: See the ngram for [inveterate optimist vs. inveterate pessimist](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inveterate+optimist%2Cinveterate+pessimist&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinveterate%20optimist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinveterate%20pessimist%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cinveterate%20optimist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinveterate%20pessimist%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be verified in OALD that this adjective is often disapproving.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/inveterate?q=inveterate)) **inveterate** adjective BrE  /ɪnˈvetərət/ AmE  /ɪnˈvetərət/
> [usually before noun] (formal, often disapproving)
> ​(of a person) always doing something or enjoying something, and unlikely to stop
> ♦ an inveterate liar
> ♦ He was an inveterate traveller

There is nothing disapproving about the word "traveller", for instance.

A research in Google Books shows that the most frequent nouns used with this adjective are not disapproving in meaning but instead negative in meaning; out of the six in the ngram only one is disapproving (prejudice), while four connote negative tendencies (enemy, foe, hatred, hostility).

[image]

*Habit (neither disapproving nor negative cases)*

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Formation_of_Character/L4frAgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22inveterate+habit%22&pg=PT15&printsec=frontcover)) He developed a handsome shaggy white coat, a quiet, well featured face, and betrayed his low origin only by one inveterate habit; carts he took no notice of, but never a carriage, small or great, appeared in sight but he ran yelping at …

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_United_Presbyterian_Magazine/uBIEAAAAQAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22inveterate+habit%22&pg=PA206&printsec=frontcover)) In Mr Alexander's case the habit is seen to less advantage by reason of his voice , which is hollow , and has certainly not been improved by an inveterate habit of snuff - taking in which he used to indulge

**Other nouns (neither disapproving nor negative cases)**

*reader, talker, arguer*

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Essays/bEA1AQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22inveterate%22&pg=PA144&printsec=frontcover)) Lady Rachel is an inveterate reader, an inveterate talker, and an inveterate arguer.

*writer*

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Dictionary_of_British_Educationists/Qc7eCwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22inveterate+writer%22&pg=PT208&printsec=frontcover)) He was an inveterate writer of books, articles and reviews chiefly in the fields of history, politics and biography.

*actor*

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Robert_Downey_Jr_from_Brat_to_Icon/trmQBAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22inveterate+actor%22&pg=PT225&printsec=frontcover)) Already an inveterate actor by the time the movie was made, having first acted in his father's movie Pound at age five, Downey's role in *Less Than Zero* garnered him critical acclaim.

*fighter pilot*

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Pacific_Air/eexYgXPQvuYC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22inveterate+fighter%22&pg=PA622&printsec=frontcover)) Though now slower of gate, his eyes, intellect and reflexes remain in good order. An inveterate fighter pilot, Vraciu is still wont to practice his skills. As he drives a highway off-ramp, Alex Vraciu will on occasion get on the six ...

**The case of "friend" and "enemy"**

There could be as many as 76 cases of "[inveterate friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inveterate%20friend%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)" and as many as 253 "[inveterate enemy](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inveterate%20enemy%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)".

The conclusion could  be, therefore, that this adjective is not associated predominantly with nouns that are disapproving, or in other words that identify a negative trait, but instead that it is associated predominantly,  with nouns that are negative in meaning (The difference must be clear: in "a distaste for raw meat" or in  "a healthy hatred for Nazi endoctrination" the words "distaste" and "hatred" are not disapproving but merely negative.); What is certain is that it is far from being associated predominently with disapproving terms and far from being associated exclusively to a set comprising disapproving terms and terms with a negative meaning.

Answer (score 4):

It was only when I reached [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/inveterate) that I came across a caveat referring directly to the usual but not obligatory pejorative aspect attaching to this word:

> **inveterate** [adjective] [usually before noun] (formal, often disapproving):
>
> ​(used of a person) always doing something or enjoying something, and
> unlikely to stop
>
> - an inveterate liar
> - He was an inveterate traveller.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/inveterate) allows the non-pejorative possibility:

> **inveterate** [adjective] [attributive]
>
> (1) Having a particular habit, activity, or interest that is
> long-established and unlikely to change.

The first two examples of real-life quotes they list both contain the strong collocation 'inveterate gamblers' and they really set the tone. The second example is

> - *They are inveterate gamblers, drink as much beer as their wages will permit, are devoted to bawdy jokes, and use probably the foulest
>   language in the world.*

The breakdown of the head nouns in the examples Lexico gives is:

{**negative / pejorative**}: gambler/s: (6)
smoker/s: (1)
coward/s: (1)
social climber/s: (1)
procrastinator/s: (1)
gossip/s: (1)
liar/s: (1)
cheat/s: (1)
skirt chaser/s: (1)
hoarder/s: (1)
party-goer/s: (1) (the last two certainly pejorative or tongue-in-cheek when twinned with 'inveterate')

..........................

{**neutral / indeterminate**}: Cold War-rior/s: (1)
television watcher/s: (1)
adventurer/s: (1)
essayist/s and letter writer/s: (1)
jazz fan/s: (1)
networker/s: (1)
multi-tasker/s: (1)
correspondent/s: (1)
home movie-maker/s: (1)
critic/s of liberal media bias: (1)
optimist/s: (1)
people watcher/s: (1)

..........................

{**approbatory**}

grassroots activist/s and organiser/s: (1) (we'll give this the benefit of the doubt)
crusader/s (1) (from the context)
good guy/s: (1) (though elsewhere this could be a sarcastic, negative usage)

..........................

I've avoided classifying 'opponent to Central Government' as too contentious.

Lexico also has a sub-sense where the head noun is a feeling, habit or the like (rather than a subset of people). 'Hostility' and 'hatred' appear in the earlier examples, though 'idealism and enthusiasm' and 'good manners' (!) buck the negative trend.

So I'd summarise and conclude;

(1) 'Inveterate' is certainly used (of people and their beliefs / behaviours) in 'neutral' and even approbatory statements, although

(2) the large majority of occurrences involve, in line with the OLD caveat, disapproval.

This means that

(3) care needs to be taken when a non-pejorative sense is intended that context counter the strong negative pull. Of course, a quirky effect may result, which may (or may not) be considered desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Historical associations with damaging habits (you are yourself familiar with "inveterate liar", I reflexively recall "inveterate gambler") has cemented 'inveterate' as a term for which a fatal habit is a corollary.

Of course, there is nothing logically or grammatically incorrect about following the term with a positive habit, but it rings jarring in the context of historical usage. This is most likely because damaging habits themselves often denote a pathology and compulsion not associated with positive activities like charity or any other activity that might denote selflessness.